# Wordpress Query Posts then put into Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to have output of an WP_Query to an array.for example an array of my last 10 post titles or an array of last post urls

Answer (score 2):

If you want to collect the results from `WP_Query()` into another array, you can try this:

```
$my_array=array();

// the query
$args=array('post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page'=>10,'orderby'=>'date', 'order'=>'ASC');
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
        $my_array[]=get_the_title(get_the_ID());
    endwhile;
endif;

// debug: 
print_r($my_array);
print_r($my_query);
```

And this example will give you the 10 last post titles into the array `$my_array()`

Comment: it just print array() that so I have posts in my wordpress

Comment: hmm..., it works for me, where are you using it? I updated the code with get_the_ID() inside get_the_title().